# Laravel 5.2 database connection don't work

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-5

I have a problem with laravel.

I have a connexion to a test database it's works but when I change the information for the production database it's not works.

Migration always migrate on the test database and not the production...

If you know if there is something else to change other than database.php in config directory, it will help me !

Thank's !

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: You should change your .env file, not the database config itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually you should use .env file for that purpose.

here is a sample values set in .env for production

```
APP_ENV=production
APP_DEBUG=false

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_DATABASE=somedatabasename
DB_USERNAME=app_user
DB_PASSWORD=jdfnfjdfae126
```

How it works

lets say config/database.php has following value

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

this means check for the environment variable `DB_CONNECTION` set in .env first, if its not set or null get 'mysql' from the config file, which is the mysql defined in config connections array in that file(database.php)

**EDIT**

as you have mentioned that you are using oracle driver. I think when you run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=oracle
```

there will be a config file publish inside config folder. If config file is not publish, the package will automatically use what is declared on your .env file database configuration.

this file `config/oracle.php`

```
<?php
return [
    'oracle' => [
        'driver'        => 'oracle',
        'tns'           => env('DB_TNS', ''),
        'host'          => env('DB_HOST', ''),
        'port'          => env('DB_PORT', '1521'),
        'database'      => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username'      => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password'      => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset'       => env('DB_CHARSET', 'AL32UTF8'),
        'prefix'        => env('DB_PREFIX', ''),
        'prefix_schema' => env('DB_SCHEMA_PREFIX', ''),
    ],
];
```

similarly you can update the values here or mention it directly on .env file. Lets say your database name is mydatabase the value in

array would be

```
'database'      => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mydatabase'),
```

if mentioned in .env file it would be

```
DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
```

> Recommended way is to use .env file even though you publish the config
>   file.so that you can ignore it in version control.

Comment: I forgot one things. I use oracle database. To connect oracle database i use this package : https://github.com/yajra/laravel-oci8     I'ts not the original use of laravel x)

Comment: @ValentinBregeon see now.hope it helps. if it helped and fixed your problem please mark as a correct answer. :)

Comment: It's ok !!!!! Thank's a lot @aimme I have to do this php artisan route:cache && php artisan config:cache && php artisan view:clear

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit .env file, this is the file that have the configuration to connect to database.

Hope it's usefull.